# How to set the background color of a select from the currently selected option using Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to set the background color of a select based on the currently selected option which contains its color.  I'm stuck on how to get the styling set (I'm using Angular 4).

An example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
<select class="form-control" [ngStyle]="this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('style')"
                        [(ngModel)]="result.Id"
                        name="test"
                        required>
                    <option *ngFor="let weight of riskWeights" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': weight.color}" [ngValue]="weight.Id">{{weight.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

Where I'm going wrong is trying to get the currently selected item and setting the style:  [ngStyle]="this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('style')".  I can't get the syntax/technique right for reading the currently selected item's background color and apply it to the select.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set the background of `option` instead of the `select`

You can set the color of a select using the option's value as follows,

```
<select [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color}" [(ngModel)]="color">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow"> Yellow </option>
</select>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/color-select)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't use value as my options are not color objects, I just have a color property on the object.  I still need to now the id of the object that was selected so [(ngModel)] needs to set the id.